# python application migration from python-2.6 to python-3

Tags: 14.04, python3, python-2.7

I'm migrating my python application from python-2.6 to python 3.
My application has been developed on Ubuntu 10.04 system having python 2.6 support. Now i want to make it work on Ubuntu 14.04 with python 3. Can i make python application totally independent of python-2?

Please share your views / ideas.

Appreciate your help!!

Thanks,
Mrudula

Comment: There is nothing technical that can prevent you from that.

Comment: Thanks! Can I remove all python 2.7 packages ? Can I have only python3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If you type `python3` on Terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 you will have access to Python 3. I mean it comes by default in it. But you will have to change certain parts of your source code (certain packages are renamed in Python 3)

Comment: Ubuntu itself needs Python 2. Apparently this won't be the case in 16.04 but until then you can just *not use it*. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Can you? Sure.

Consider for a moment that Python 2 is going to be supported into 2020 officially and possibly longer unofficially. **Do you *need* to port this to Python 3?** You could be lazy and let 2020's mrudula figure this one out.

I'm sure you're aware that Python 2 and 3 aren't directly compatible. You probably have to make a few changes to port between them. There are tools like `2to3` (included in Ubuntu) that make this *much* easier —at least more automated— but there are likely still libraries you're using that rely on Python 2.x that you'll need to replace.

Or you can stick with Python 2.7.

Either which way, I've been through the same process as you're doing now with several small Django apps. The biggest single improvement I can suggest (if you aren't already doing it) is to **move to a virtualenv** (the `venv` module in Py3k). Keeping things separated from the system has allowed a lot of pulled hair to grow back.

I'd suggest the following itinerary:

1. Install 14.04 on another machine (VM, whatever)
2. Create a Python ***2*** virtualenv for your app and activate it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
   /usr/bin/virtualenv venv
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   pip install -U pip
   ```
3. Install any requirements you *know* you need with `pip`. If you've activated a virtualenv, it will install them locally, no `sudo` required.
4. Get things *working*. This is an iterative process of running it until it realises you're missing something.
5. When you are certain you know it all works and you have all your requirements, dump them (and version constraints) in a file called `requirements.txt`

If you're happy with Python 2, you can stop there. Migrate that onto a real server (if it isn't on one already) and commit your `requirements.txt` to version control so you can restore your environment really quickly in the future if you need to.

If you want to continue to Python 3, the path is much clearer:

6. Delete your Python 2 virtualenv, create a Python ***3*** venv and install your requirements:

   ```
   deactivate
   /usr/bin/python3 -mvenv venv
   pip install -U pip
   pip install -Ur requirements
   ```
7. Unleash `2to3` (and other tools) on your source and finish the port manually. Make sure you have a backup of what you have already. It's not a vastly complicated tool (see `2to3 --help`) but typically speaking, this should be enough to get you going (remember to backup first, this will write changes):

   ```
   2to3 -wf all .
   ```

Comment: Thank you!!  Appreciate your suggestions. I have embedded application which i can not run without target board. Recently have migrated My Ubuntu operating system from 10.04 to 14.04 on target board. And Now migrating my python Application too. Could you please share brief about how to break a link between python 2 and 3. So my application run only run using python 3. As python 2.7 is also installed on Ubuntu 14.04. and /usr/bin/python is  pointing to /usr/bin/pyhton2.7. Can i delete all packages related to pyhton 2.7?  Please share ideas..

Comment: @mrudula No! If you do anything to Python 2, Ubuntu 14.04 will not properly work any more! Just run your script like `python3 /path/to/script.py` instead of `python /path/to/script.py`. Or, if you're directly executing it from the terminal instead of passing the script's file name as argument to the python interpreter, you have to modify the shebang line (first line of the file) of the script to `#! /usr/bin/env python3` instead of `#! /usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: @mrudula Seriously, **ignore the system's version of Python**, use a virtuaenv, live a long a happy life. It's that simple.

Comment: Could you please brife about virtuaenv? Do you have any idea on 2to3 conversion tool on ubuntu 14.04? Please share details how to install python tool to convert from 2to3. Thanks

Comment: Just speaking practically —there will be bits I can't help you with— you're going to have to learn to Google things like "python virtualenv" "python 2to3". They'll tell you all this. Nonetheless, I've added some commands to the answer.

Comment: import error for builtin module:   import builtins giving error as ImportError: No module named builtins Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047745/where-is-the-builtin-module-in-python3-why-was-it-renamed

Comment: Thanks Oli!! I guess, virtuaenv will not work for my case. As I am having all python code which is running on Embedded system with very small and cutomised ubuntu 14.04 support. Any idea how to proceed on the same?

Comment: Huh? Why not? That error is about incompatible code, nothing inherent to virtualenv/venv.

Comment: Yup!! I resolved that error!! But in previous comments as you have mentioned to use virtuaenv for running python-3. regarding the same point. The concern is here i will not b able to make / setup virtuaenv on target / Embedded board.